# brew install fontforge error yosemite

Tags: homebrew, osx-yosemite, fontforge

I'm on OS X Yosemite and am trying to install fontforge via brew. When I try to install it I get the following error. I'd like to use fontforge to try fontcustom and grunt-webfont. What does this error mean? Do I need to install something else first?

```
$ brew install fontforge --with-python
==> Downloading https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/archive/2.0.20140101.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/fontforge-2.0.20140101.tar.gz
==> ./autogen.sh
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/fontforge/2.0.20140101 --without-cairo
==> make
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libgdraw_la-gmatrixedit.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and reinstalling 10.10 XCode Command Line Tools solved it!

:-)

Good luck -

Comment: brew doctor also helped fix the issue for me